# Convert Spark Data Frame to org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd, apache-spark-mllib

I'm very new to scala and spark 2.1.
I'm trying to calculate correlation between many elements in a data frame which looks like this:

```
item_1 | item_2 | item_3 | item_4
     1 |      1 |      4 |      3
     2 |      0 |      2 |      0
     0 |      2 |      0 |      1
```

Here is what I've tried:

```
val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
  Seq((1, 1, 4, 3),
      (2, 0, 2, 0),
      (0, 2, 0, 1)
).toDF("item_1", "item_2", "item_3", "item_4")


val items = df.select(array(df.columns.map(col(_)): _*)).rdd.map(_.getSeq[Double](0))
```

And calcualte correlation between elements:

```
val correlMatrix: Matrix = Statistics.corr(items, "pearson")
```

With followning error message:

```
<console>:89: error: type mismatch;
found   : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Seq[Double]]
 required: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector]
       val correlMatrix: Matrix = Statistics.corr(items, "pearson")
```

I don't know how to create the `org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector]` from a data frame.

This might be a really easy task but I kinda struggle with it and I'm happy for any advice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can for example use `VectorAssembler`. Assemble vectors and convert to `RDD`

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler

val rows = new VectorAssembler().setInputCols(df.columns).setOutputCol("vs")
  .transform(df)
  .select("vs")
  .rdd
```

Extract `Vectors` from `Row`:

- Spark 1.x:

  ```
  rows.map(_.getAs[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector](0))
  ```
- Spark 2.x:

  ```
  rows
    .map(_.getAs[org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector](0))
    .map(org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors.fromML)
  ```

Regarding your code:

- You have `Integer` columns not `Double`.
- Data is not an `array` so the you cannot use `_.getSeq[Double](0)`.

Comment: Thank you very much - that's the solution I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to perform pearson correlations, you don't really have to use RDDs and Vectors.  Here's an example of performing pearson correlations directly on DataFrame columns (the columns in question are Doubles types).

**Code:**

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{SQLContext, Row, DataFrame}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType, DoubleType}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._


val rb = spark.read.option("delimiter","|").option("header","false").option("inferSchema","true").format("csv").load("rb.csv").toDF("name","beerId","brewerId","abv","style","appearance","aroma","palate","taste","overall","time","reviewer").cache()

rb.agg(
    corr("overall","taste"),
    corr("overall","aroma"),
    corr("overall","palate"),
    corr("overall","appearance"),
    corr("overall","abv")
    ).show()
```

In this example, I'm importing a dataframe (with a custom delimiter, no header, and inferred data types), and then simply performing an agg function against the dataframe which has multiple correlations inside it.

**Output:**

```
+--------------------+--------------------+---------------------+-------------------------+------------------+
|corr(overall, taste)|corr(overall, aroma)|corr(overall, palate)|corr(overall, appearance)|corr(overall, abv)|
+--------------------+--------------------+---------------------+-------------------------+------------------+
|  0.8762432795943761|   0.789023067942876|   0.7008942639550395|       0.5663593891357243|0.3539158620897098|
+--------------------+--------------------+---------------------+-------------------------+------------------+
```

As you can see from the results, the (overall, taste) columns are highly correlated, while (overall, abv) not so much.

Here's a link to the [Scala Docs DataFrame page which has the Aggregation Correlation Function](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@corr(column1:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,column2:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column).

Comment: Thank you for this way. It does the work but I have more than 300 columns to calculate

Comment: is there a way to calculate this for many many Columns without specifically define every combination?